# Volley соединение в BaseAdpater классе в динамичном списке

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Здравствуйте, суть в том, что не пойму как в динамичном списке и в view элементах, законнектиться к Volley для операций. Вот урезанный код. Как решить проблемку?

```
    public class Adapter_Pre_Cart extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Activity activity;
private List<Item> items;
private String[] data = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

ImageLoader imageLoader=AppController.getmInstance().getmImageLoader();
public Adapter_Pre_Cart(Activity activity,List<Item> items){
    this.activity=activity;
    this.items=items;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(inflater==null){
        inflater=(LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    if(convertView ==null){
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_describe,null);
    }
    if(imageLoader==null)
        imageLoader=AppController.getmInstance().getmImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView imageView= (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.networkImageView_cart);

    TextView title= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item_name);
    Button button=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_add_to_cart);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());\\ проблемка тут, не вызывается контекст.
        }
    });
```

Comment: `Volley.newRequestQueue(activity)` - не поможет разве?

Comment: или Volley.newRequestQueue(activity).add(stringRequest);

Comment: Спасибо.Плюсанул бы)